# on ubuntu 13.10 multiple hits on ctrl+tab makes my intellij 13 keyboard stuck (no key works)

Tags: ubuntu, intellij-idea, ubuntu-13.10

I have to restart my intellij every like 20 minutes whenever I hit multiple times <kbd>ctrl+tab</kbd>.  It looks like clicking this multiple time on my ubuntu 13.10 + intellij 13.01 makes my intellij stuck.  on intellij 12 same OS everything is just fine.
anyway to work around this?

Comment: Same issue here, so annoying!

Comment: IntelliJ 14.1 + Ubuntu 14.10 still affected, although ctrl+click works

Answer (score 56, accepted):

workaround try this when it happens:

> ibus-daemon -rd

http://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-115661

http://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-78860

Comment: The answer saved many hours of mine. hence awarding a bounty (in 24 hours)

Comment: After using 'ibus-daemon -rd' only English works in IDEA and other languages stops working (for my case Persian)

Comment: @MohsenKashi Yes, you should run `setxkbmap` after that to set languages correctly.

Answer (score 3):

Restarting ibus-deamon may cause issues with other applications¹ or even crash IntelliJ, according to [IDEA-78860](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-78860). However it also suggests there are 2 alternate solutions:

- Disabling IBUS support for idea. This is done with an empty `XMODIFIERS` environment variable when starting IntelliJ. For example, add this at the beginning of `idea.sh` and restart IntelliJ:

  ```sh
  # workaround for https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-78860
  export XMODIFIERS=
  ```
- Force IBUS to keep the order of events by setting `IBUS_ENABLE_SYNC_MODE=1` for ibus-daemon². In my case I implemented it by adding the following to my `~/.xsessionrc` (create the file if it does not exist) and restart my session:

  ```sh
  # workaround for https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-78860
  export IBUS_ENABLE_SYNC_MODE=1
  ```

*(I actually did both so I don't know which one fixes it for me)*

If this works for you, this has the advantage of fixing the problem once and for all, and you shouldn't have to restart ibus-daemon any more.

The only inconvenient is that you need to restart IntelliJ or even your whole session to apply it the first time.

¹ <sub>In my case dead keys didn't work any more afterwards in some applications like Skype.</sub>
² <sub>Apparently IBUS should have the sync mode enabled by default in a future release, see [issue 1697](https://code.google.com/p/ibus/issues/detail?id=1697) and [the corresponding commit](https://github.com/ibus/ibus/commit/b58351ec2f7c057dcfe0aff883064039702a56d7).</sub>

Answer (score 0):

In my case, it was something different. I got this weird behaviour after I entered my licence credentials to Idea. I suppose it created a new Jet Brains user's account for me with an ability to sync IDE settings enabled by default. My suggestion that it has overridden my setting (including keyboard bindings) with some default ones created by Jet Brains.

Fortunately, I had previously set up my `Settings Repository` on `Github`. I rolled back to my old settings pressing `File -> Settings Repository -> Override Local`.

The issue was on macOS in Database editor.